# Store unique substrings from many lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file which looks like this.

```
a/b/X/Y/1
a/b/X/Y/2
a/b/X/Y/3
...
a/b/X/Z/1
a/b/X/Z/2
a/b/X/Z/3
...
a/c/M/N/1
a/c/M/N/2
a/c/M/N/3
...
a/d/F/G/123
a/d/F/G/124
a/d/F/G/125
```

Symbols are placeholders.

I'm interested in the unique substrings consisting of the first and second symbol separated by a `"/"`. In other words, in the example I want to build a list consisting of `["a/b", "a/c", "a/d"]`.

How to do this in Python idiomatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example without much magic.
The first we write to the file but you can remove that (it is just to easily show you how it works).

```
file_content = """a/b/X/Y/1
a/b/X/Y/2
a/b/X/Y/3
a/b/X/Z/1
a/b/X/Z/2
a/b/X/Z/3
a/c/M/N/1
a/c/M/N/2
a/c/M/N/3
a/d/F/G/123
a/d/F/G/124
a/d/F/G/125
"""

# This can be removed as it is just to show how it works
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_content)

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

result = set()
for line in lines:
    a, b, *rest = line.split('/')
    result.add(f'{a}/{b}')

print(result)
```

Comment: for your example you can just to `lines = file_content.splitlines()`

Answer (score 2):

I would split the lines according to `/` with a maxsplit of 2, discard the last item (which is the rest of the string that you don't need), join back the strings, then put that in a set comprehension to remove duplicates:

```
with open("file.txt") as lines:
    result = {"/".join(s.split("/",maxsplit=2)[:-1]) for s in lines}
```

result:

```
>>> result
{'a/b', 'a/c', 'a/d'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_unique(input_file):
    output = set()
    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            output.add(line.strip()[0:3])

    return list(output)

print(find_unique("input_file"))
```

This gives:

```
['a/b', 'a/d', 'a/c']
```

for file containing:

```
a/b/X/Y/1
a/b/X/Y/2
a/b/X/Y/3
a/b/X/Z/1
a/b/X/Z/2
a/b/X/Z/3
a/c/M/N/1
a/c/M/N/2
a/c/M/N/3
a/d/F/G/123
a/d/F/G/124
a/d/F/G/125
```

Comment: `line.strip()[0:3]` is assuming that identifiers can only have 1 char long (and no need to strip either with that slicing)